# How to make sure data is correct if two DML happened at ths same time in Django ORM?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-orm

I use `mysql` and `InnoDB` engine for my `Django` project. I have a table which is like following, the `queue` field default value is `0`

```
class Task(models.Model):
    task_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    queue = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have two process, one is to insert a record based on the max queue in the table.

```
 max_queue = Task.objects.all().annotate(data=Max('queue')).values('data')
 queue_number = max_queue[0]['data'] + 1
 record = {'task_id':task_id, 'queue': queue_number}
 Task.objects.create(**record)
```

Another process is to decrement the value of `queue` for each record by 1 which `queue` is not equal to 0

```
query_list = Task.objects.filter(~Q(task_queue=0))
for query in query_list:
    Task.objects.filter(task_id=task_id).update(queue=query.queue - 1)
```

Here what I am concerned is if **the two process happened at the same time**. For example, if the later process is about to decrement every value. While at the same time, the first process inserts a new value. In this case, there woule be some mistakes.

How should I do it? Anyone has a good idea, thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) for this purpose, it will lock the records you are updating until the end of the transaction

```python
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models import Q

with transaction.atomic():
    query_list = Task.objects.select_for_update().filter(~Q(queue=0))
    for query in query_list:
        query.queue -= 1
        query.save()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here I have a question, do I need to lock the entire table in my case? If yes, does Django support it?

Comment: `select_for_update` will lock only selected in queryset rows, not whole table. I guess it's what you need

Comment: Minor correction: `select_for_update` will lock all _examined_ rows, even if some of those examined rows are filtered out by query conditions. This is why it's important to create indexes to minimize the examined rows.

Comment: I got another question. Do I have to add a `transaction.atomic()` in my first process (the `create` process)? Since it has to find the max of `queue`.